# Eclipse/Java equivalent to Microsoft ASP.NET Model View Control Framework

Tags: java, eclipse, model-view-controller, frameworks

Does anyone know if there is any equivalent to Microsoft's ASP.NET Model View Control Framework with Visual Studio/C# but for Eclipse with Java?

Or put it another way one could build a website in C# using MS Visual Studio with ASP.NET MVC,  is there anything similar for Java using the Eclipse IDE?

I've built up good knowledge with Java and the Eclipse IDE creating some Android Apps that I'd like to leverage, now I need to turn my attention to web apps and I'd like to stick with Java and the Eclipse IDE.    Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a bunch.  I'd check out [Play!](http://www.playframework.org/)
but there are also: [Apache Wicket](http://wicket.apache.org/), [Spring MVC](http://www.springsource.org/) and some others.

There is also a version of [Play! for Scala](http://scala.playframework.org/) which is a bonus if you intend on moving up from Java to [Scala](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scala_%28programming_language%29) one day.

There is also a similar question with a more detailed answer here:
[Choosing a Java Web Framework now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084169/choosing-a-java-web-framework-now)

Comment: Thanks a mil Matt, I'll check them out and see how I get on, might take a quick look at Scala. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Spring MVC is worth a look. Spring goes way beyond "just" MVC, with APIS for DB, JMS, and loads more, which may be a little offputting if you're just keen to get to grips with an MVC platform, but it's arguably worth it.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/

Comment: Thanks Brian, I'll check out Spring MVC as well, Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are a lot of them. Your problem is that there are too many, actually. Narrowing down the list can be a challenge. Everybody has their favorites (mine is Apache Tapestry, because it's actually fun to use, and very powerful).

My recommendation is to pick 3 or 4 (I'd go with Tapestry, GWT, Spring MVC and Wicket), and then spend a couple days working through the introductory tutorial that each of them offers. You'll soon know which one feels right to you, and you'll be basing your decision on your own experience rather than the strongly-worded opinions of strangers.

Comment: Hi Bob, Wow, no kidding, feel like I just opened a can of worms, I think you're right, this is going to take a bit of time, I need to work my way through them until I find one that suits me, Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

[Tapestry](http://tapestry.apache.org/) or [Wicket](http://wicket.apache.org/) is worth trying.